# One Segfaulting Skip List, One Ruined Weekend (C Programming)

Tags: c, list, debugging, segmentation-fault, skip-lists

I'm a CS student, and my Halloween weekend just got ruined by a programming assignment I can't debug. This might be one of the few questions on here that doesn't immediately get marked "duplicate."

The assignment is a "Skip List," or a singly-linked list (programmed in C) where each node has a variable-size array of pointers, determined by random "coin" tosses. 3 successful tosses results in a height of 3, etc. Each array is then linked to other arrays at similar heights - a seventh level linked to the next seventh level, sixth to the next sixth, all the way down to first, or array element 0, which is naturally linked to the very next item in the list.

Since most items don't have a higher level, this acts as a great way for searching in log(n) time, rather than simply n. It's dramatically faster for insert, remove, and search, at the cost of being more expensive in memory. This is just the theory - here's a picture: [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

Many of you will already know this stuff, but I just wanted to explain it a little and show that I actually do understand the basics of what's happening here.

The issue is a random segfault that's screwing up all of the provided tests with "CODE 6 - ABORT" messages. When I run my main file, I randomly get segfaults at the indicated locations in the code (<-----Segfaults) - it happens about half the time, and can be at either line. The tests also give me a lot of "bad pointer" and "minmap chunk error" messages.

I'm at my wits' end on this. I have a 93 in the class, but that drops to an 87 if I can't get this abominable thing finished.

Any assistance is appreciated, and here's the code:

**Definitions**

```
typedef int data_t;

typedef struct skip_node {
    data_t data;
    size_t height;
    struct skip_node **next;
} skip_node_t;

typedef struct skip_set {
    skip_node_t *head;
    size_t max_height;
    size_t size;
} skip_set_t;
```

**Main method causing the random fault**

```
skip_set_t set;
skip_set_init(&set);
skip_set_add(&set, 4);
skip_set_add(&set, 3);
skip_set_clear(&set);
skip_set_t set2;
skip_set_init(&set2);
skip_set_add(&set2, 1); //faults here
```

**...And finally, the devil's data structure:**

```
    #include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "skip_set.h"

/***********************
        PART 1
***********************/

//Initialize
void skip_set_init(skip_set_t *set)
{
   //Set
   set->size = 0;
   set->max_height = 1;
   set->head = malloc(sizeof(skip_node_t));

   //Sentinel
   set->head->data = 0; 
   set->head->height = set->max_height;
   set->head->next = malloc(sizeof(skip_node_t*) * set->max_height); 
}

//Clear
void skip_set_clear(skip_set_t *set)
{   
   if (set->head == NULL)
      return;

   skip_node_t* this;
   skip_node_t* nex;
   this = set->head->next[0];
   while(this != NULL)
   {
      nex = this->next[0];
      free(this->next);
      this->next = NULL;
      free(this);
      this = nex;
   } 
   set->size = 0;

   for (int ii = 0; ii < set->max_height; ii++)
      set->head->next[ii] = NULL; 
}

//Size
size_t skip_set_size(skip_set_t *set)
{
   return set->size;
}

//Free
void skip_set_free(skip_set_t *set)
{
   skip_set_clear(set);

   free(set->head->next);
   set->head->next = NULL;

   free(set->head);
   set->head = NULL;
}

//Add
void skip_set_add(skip_set_t *set, data_t value)
{
   printf("Add Start\n");
   if (skip_set_contains(set, value))
      return;

   int new_height = 1;    

   while(rand() % 2 == 0)
   {
      new_height++;
   }
   printf("Add One\n");
   if (set->max_height < new_height)
   {
      skip_node_t** arr = malloc(sizeof(skip_node_t*) * new_height);

      for (int ii = 0; ii < set->max_height; ii++)
         arr[ii] = set->head->next[ii];

      for (int jj = set->max_height; jj < new_height; jj++)
         arr[jj] = NULL; 
      printf("Add Two\n");
      free(set->head->next);
      set->head->next = NULL;  
      set->head->next = arr;
      set->max_height = new_height;
      set->head->height = new_height; 
      printf("Add Three\n");  
   } 

   skip_node_t* new_node = (skip_node_t*)malloc(sizeof(skip_node_t));

   skip_node_t** arr = calloc(new_height, sizeof(skip_node_t*));
   new_node->next = arr;
   new_node->height = new_height;
   new_node->data = value;

   skip_node_t* cur_node = set->head; 
   int cur_level = set->max_height - 1; 
   printf("Add Four\n");
   while (cur_level >= 0)
   {
      printf("ABreak 1\n");
      while ((cur_node->next[cur_level] != NULL) && (cur_node->next[cur_level]->data < value))//<-----Segfaults
      {
         printf("ABreak 2\n");
         cur_node = cur_node->next[cur_level];
         printf("ABreak 3\n");
      }
      printf("ABreak 4\n");
      if (cur_level < new_height)
      {
         printf("ABreak 5\n");
         new_node->next[cur_level] = cur_node->next[cur_level];
         cur_node->next[cur_level] = new_node;
         printf("ABreak 6\n");
      }
      printf("ABreak 7\n");
      cur_level--;       
   }

   set->size++;
   printf("Add End\n");   
}

//Remove
void skip_set_remove(skip_set_t *set, data_t value)
{
   printf("Remove Start\n");
   if (!skip_set_contains(set, value))
      return;

   skip_node_t* tbf;
   skip_node_t* cur_node = set->head;

   int cur_level = set->max_height - 1;
   printf("Remove 1\n");
   while (cur_level >= 0)
   {
      while ((cur_node->next[cur_level] != NULL) && (cur_node->next[cur_level]->data < value))
      {
         cur_node = cur_node->next[cur_level];
      }

      if ((cur_node->next[cur_level] != NULL) && (cur_node->next[cur_level]->data == value))
      {
         tbf = cur_node->next[0];
         cur_node->next[cur_level] = cur_node->next[cur_level]->next[cur_level];
         if (cur_node == NULL && cur_node->next[cur_level] == NULL)
            set->max_height--;
      }      
      cur_level--;       
   }
   printf("Remove 2\n");
   free(tbf->next);
   printf("Remove 3\n");
   free(tbf);
   set->size--;   
   printf("Remove End\n");
}

//Pop
data_t skip_set_pop(skip_set_t *set)
{
   printf("Pop Start\n");
   data_t lazyCSstudent = set->head->next[0]->data;
   skip_set_remove(set, lazyCSstudent);
   printf("Pop End\n");
   return lazyCSstudent;
}

//Contains
bool skip_set_contains(skip_set_t *set, data_t value)
{ 
   printf("Contains Start\n");
   skip_node_t* this = set->head;
   int i = set->max_height - 1;
   printf("Contains Mid\n");
   while(i >= 0)
   {
      printf("CBreak One\n");
      while((this->next[i] != NULL) && (this->next[i]->data < value)) ///<-----Segfaults
      {
         printf("CBreak Two\n");
         this = this->next[i];
         printf("CBreak Three\n");
      }
      i--;
      printf("CBreak Four\n");
   }
   printf("Contains End\n");
   return (this->next[0] != NULL) && (this->next[0]->data == value);   
}
```

Contains and Add are the problem, though there might be other stuff, too. Weirdly, this usually happens after I free another list, but I can't find any artifacts from it in my code.

If you solve this for me, I'll mail a $20 and a plate of cookies to the address of your choice.

Comment: Try to run this thing under valgrind to see what's wrong with your pointers.

Comment: Most likely cause is that you are writing to random memory using an uninitialized pointer. These types of issues typically result in a warning from the compiler. Make sure you have the warning level at maximum, and fix every warning.

Comment: FWIW I get "warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch" three times.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Well set out question, properly formatted code - makes a pleasant change.

Comment: Welcome to SO (also). Please note that it is not required (in the most wide sense) to edit your post and add the solution and "FIXED" to it. The presence of an accepted answer is indication enough. (Comment Tip: to target 1 (and no more) specific user, use "@abligh: ..'. That way he will see a comment reminder in his In Box.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip_set_init()` sets `max_height` to `1` and allocates memory for a pointer array

```
set->max_height = 1;
...
set->head->next = malloc(sizeof(skip_node_t*) * set->max_height);
```

but does not not initialise the elements of the array `next`. Then in `skip_set_add()`

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < set->max_height; ii++)
    arr[ii] = set->head->next[ii];

for (int jj = set->max_height; jj < new_height; jj++)
    arr[jj] = NULL;
```

the first element is copied from the uninitialised array, and the other elements [1..] are set to `NULL`.

So the first element `arr[0]` is an uninitialised value.

I haven't looked any further than this.

Answer (score 2):

The standard advice is this:

1. Make sure your code compiles without warnings with -Wall - this catches a pile of stuff.
2. Run your code under `valgrind` and ensure it runs without warnings - this catches a pile more stuff.
3. Run your code in `gdb` (or whatever debugger you are using) and carefully look at the stack trace.
4. Take a copy of your code, and try removing and simplifying stuff until you get a minimal example (probably removing something will fix it, in which case you know what is broken)
5. In the unlikely event you still have an issue, post the resultant minimal code here. It will be easier to debug.

Here's some advice based on reading your code:

1. Allocate memory with `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`, which zeroes everything (add a dummy extra parameter of 1). This makes finding issues easier. About 10 seconds after I wrote this (but not had not yet published it) *WeatherVane* posted an answer showing one problem that would have been solved by this - or at least made it more obvious.
2. Write a function to check the consistency of the skip list. This will probably get you extra credit too, but is great for debugging.
3. When you are growing the skip list entry arrays, `realloc()` would make your life easier, and be less error prone. I think I beat *WeatherVane* to this one by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I'm free! I'm finally free!

user3386109 and I both came to the same conclusion - I found it, and checked the board, and he'd mentioned the same thing.

In init, I forgot to initialize set->head->next[0] to NULL, or check for that in other functions. Uninitialized pointer, and one very likely to cause a segfaulting freak-out during runtime -  especially after I built another set earlier. Not sure how that worked out, nor do I want to speculate too much.

Thanks for taking the time to help an errant CS student on Halloween. A little testing, and I've only lost 10% for lateness.

Edit: also, WeatherVane's post helped. Thanks!